# Grails - beforeInsert throwing exception null id in entry

Tags: grails-domain-class, grails-2.0

I am trying to use beforeInsert  in my user domain class.

```
 class User {

    String reEnterPassword

    static constraints = {

        password(blank: false, nullable: false, size:5..50, validator: {password, obj ->
         def reEnterPassword = obj.properties['reEnterPassword']
         if(reEnterPassword == null) return true 
         reEnterPassword == password ? true : ['invalid.matchingpasswords']
         })
        reEnterPassword(bindable:true, blank: false);
    }


    def beforeInsert = {
        password = password.encodeAsSHA()
        }

    String toString(){
        name
        }


    static transients = ['reEnterPassword']

    }
```

in my controller i have save method ( generated)

```
    def save() {
    def userInstance = new User(params)
    if (!`userInstance.save(flush: true)`) {
        render(view: "create", model: [userInstance: userInstance])
        return
    }
```

This is throwing exception 
Grails runtime exception, org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs), when domain objects save method encounters a SQL Exception

I read in the documentation for [auto timestamping](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#eventsAutoTimestamping) that
Do not attempt to flush the session within an event (such as with obj.save(flush:true)). Since events are fired during flushing this will cause a StackOverflowError.

In this case how to save my `userInstance.save(flush: true)` I tried to remove `flush:true` but still i am getting same error. if i remove flus:true..then when i need to call. When hibenate will flush all these records.

I tried the solution defined [this JIRA ticket](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-5865)
 Please help me out. Thank you

Comment: Any thing required to answer the question. Please help me out. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Can it be that you have other validation errors?

If you put your code in the beforeValidate method it will work:

```
def beforeValidate = {
     password = password.encodeAsSHA()
}
```

I guess I'm too late to help you, but I hope it helps others with the same issue.

Greetings, Urs

Answer (score 0):

Change your

```
def beforeInsert = {
    password = password.encodeAsSHA()
}
```

to

```
def beforeInsert() {
    password = password.encodeAsSHA()
}
```

and that should do the trick

Comment: Thank you for answering. But Still i am getting same error Class   org.hibernate.AssertionFailure Message  null id in com.valuelabs.bets.User entry  (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs).

Answer (score 0):

I believe if the beforeInsert method return false then you get the "null id in entry" exception.  Perhaps this is treated as an indication that validation has failed.

e.g. the following will cause the exception

```
def beforeInsert() {
  flag = false
}
```

however the following should work OK

```
def beforeInsert() {
  flag = false
  return true
}
```